# mashape api Class 'Unirest' not found error in php code

Tags: php

i am Download php source code for mashape api from 
https://github.com/composer/composer url
i install composer by the git command
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

i include

```
{
  "require" : {
    "mashape/unirest-php" : "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Unirest": "lib/"}
  }
}
```

this line of code in composer.json
and i create a new file with test.php name on root directory and include

```
require_once '/test/Unirest.php';
$response = Unirest::post("http://httpbin.org/post", array( "Accept" => "application/json" ),
  array(
    "parameter" => 23,
    "foo" => "bar"
  )
);

$response->code; // HTTP Status code
$response->headers; // Headers
$response->body; // Parsed body
$response->raw_body; // Unparsed body
```

after all the above process 
i run php source code then display class "unirest" not found 
there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for using Unirest, it's a great tool for developers, I use Unirest daily so I can help ya out:

First of all you didn't include/require the library properly with composer you need to require the autoload.php in the vendor folder generated by composer itself

Secondly you're being returned an array so for example to display the raw_body you gotta use the print_r();

Hope this helps,
Best!
The Mashape Sheriff :D

Working + Related code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$response = Unirest::post("http://httpbin.org/post", array( "Accept" => "application/json" ), array(
   "parameter" => 23,
   "foo" => "bar"
  )
);
print_r($response->raw_body);
?>
```